#  an extended question of Gromov: Every **generalized open almost complex manifold** admits a **generalized symplectic structure**? 

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-geometry, manifolds, gt.geometric-topology

**Definition** (***Open Manifolds***):An open manifold is a manifold without boundary with no compact component. For a connected manifold, "open" is equivalent to "without boundary and non-compact.
we know that every symplectic manifold admits an almost complex structure but for open manifolds , the inverse is also correct and infact ;

M.Gromov proved Every **open** almost complex manifold admits a symplectic
structure,

**So My question is** , how can we extend it for **Generalized Almost Complex manifolds**(in the sense of Hitchin and Gualtieri )?

Every **generalized open almost complex manifold** admits a **non trivial generalized symplectic
structure**?

Comment: As long as you are giving definitions of things, perhaps you could include definitions of the generalized objects.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Generalized_almost_complex_structure for instance.

Comment: Why should this be possible? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haskell, by a "generalized symplectic structure" do you mean a generalized complex structure in the sense of Hitchin and Gualtieri?

Comment: This is a good question, I don't understand why someone would like to close it. Anyway, do you know an example a generalised almost complex structure that is not isotopic to an ordinary almost complex structure?

Comment: I just cast the last vote to close, even though I agree with Dmitri that asking about h-principles for generalized almost complex structures is a perfectly good topic, for the following reasons. Haskell has a track record of asking unclear questions such as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94114/symplectic-leaves
Here, he ignored Scott's reasonable request for clarification, and did not correct the non-standard term "generalized symplectic" to "generalized complex" when I pointed it out. When I answered the question, rather trivially, he changed it to a pretty meaningless question.

Comment: Basically, I think Haskell ought to put a bit more effort into making his questions clear and precise, and ought not to change them when someone else has tried to give a clear and precise answer.

Comment: Haskell - yes of course, and thanks for your comment. Best regards,

Comment: Dear Haskell, I see that you have flagged Tim's answer with the comment that it is trivial.  I do not understand what you want the moderators to do about that.  Since you are the person who asked the question, you are responsible for precisely describing what sort of answer you want.  Finally, I don't understand why you continue to use the term "generalized symplectic", since it does not make anything easier to understand.

Comment: Since I assume it is you: could you please stop voting to reopen your old questions; it is very unlikely they will be reopened because of this but is a bit annoying to have these votes clutter a certain list. Thanks in advance. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his thesis

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401221

Marco Gualtieri explains that a generalized almost complex structure on an $n$-manifold $M$ is a reduction of the structure group of $TM \oplus T^\ast M$, which has its canonical hyperbolic quadratic form, from $O(n,n)$ to $U(n,n)$. He points out (p. 48) that since $U(n,n)$ retracts to its maximal compact subgroup $U(n)\times U(n)$, such a reduction implies a reduction of structure for $TM$ to $U(n)$, hence an almost complex structure. By Gromov's symplectic h-principle, an open manifold with a generalized almost complex structure therefore admits a symplectic form, which is an example of a generalized complex structure.

I have nothing to say, however, about the more substantial question of whether the inclusion of the generalized complex structures into the generalized almost complex structures is a highly connected map.

Comment: I have studied his thesis http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401221, in fact with your previous explanation you again repeated my question

Comment: Isn't this an answer to the question you ask in the last line of your post?